# Get the current position of ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I saw the position property but I think that is just used to set x and y, but I don't know what about recognizing current location.

Or totally how to use events income properties like onHover?

Answer (score 4):

In the following example you see how you can use `GeometryReader` to get the horizontal position of the content in the scroll view. However, I did not succeed yet in finding out how to *set* the scroll position. (Xcode 11.0 beta 6 (11M392q))

```
struct TimelineView: View {


    @State private var posX: CGFloat = 0


    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geo in

            VStack {

                Text("\(self.posX)")

                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {

                    VStack {

                        GeometryReader { innerGeo -> Text in

                            self.posX = innerGeo.frame(in: .global).minX

                            return Text("")
                        }

                        TimelineGridView()
                    }
                }
                .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height / 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where:

````
struct TimelineGridView: View {


    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { rowIndex in

                TimelineRowView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TimelineRowView: View {


    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { itemIndex in

                TimelineCellView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TimelineCellView: View {


    var body: some View {

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .bottomLeading)
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Works fine for detecting Scroll View position in Swift 5

Answer (score 3):

See [What is Geometry Reader in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729619/what-is-geometry-reader-in-swiftui), specifically the discussion about `GeometryGetter`. If you place a `GeometryGetter` at the top of your `ScrollView` contents, it will emit its frame using the binding you pass to it. The origin of this frame will be the negative content offset of the scroll view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TrackableScrollView` by [@maxnatchanon](https://medium.com/@maxnatchanon/)

Here is the code:

````swift
//
//  TrackableScrollView.swift
//  TrackableScrollView
//
//  Created by Frad LEE on 2020/6/21.
//  Copyright © 2020 Frad LEE. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

/// A trackable and scrollable view. Read [this link](https://medium.com/@maxnatchanon/swiftui-how-to-get-content-offset-from-scrollview-5ce1f84603ec) for more.
///
/// The trackable scroll view displays its content within the trackable scrollable content region.
///
/// # Usage
///
/// ``` swift
/// struct ContentView: View {
///     @State private var scrollViewContentOffset = CGFloat(0) // Content offset available to use
/// 
///     var body: some View {
///         TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: false, contentOffset: $scrollViewContentOffset) {
///             ...
///         }
///     }
/// }
/// ```

struct TrackableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let axes: Axis.Set
    let showIndicators: Bool
    @Binding var contentOffset: CGFloat
    let content: Content

    /// Creates a new instance that’s scrollable in the direction of the given axis and can show indicators while scrolling.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - axes: The scrollable axes of the scroll view.
    ///   - showIndicators: A value that indicates whether the scroll view displays the scrollable component of the content offset, in a way that’s suitable for the platform.
    ///   - contentOffset: A value that indicates  offset of content.
    ///   - content: The scroll view’s content.
    init(_ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical, showIndicators: Bool = true, contentOffset: Binding<CGFloat>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.axes = axes
        self.showIndicators = showIndicators
        _contentOffset = contentOffset
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outsideProxy in
            ScrollView(self.axes, showsIndicators: self.showIndicators) {
                ZStack(alignment: self.axes == .vertical ? .top : .leading) {
                    GeometryReader { insideProxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: [self.calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy: outsideProxy, insideProxy: insideProxy)])
                    }
                    VStack {
                        self.content
                    }
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                self.contentOffset = value[0]
            }
        }
    }

    private func calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy outsideProxy: GeometryProxy, insideProxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        if axes == .vertical {
            return outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY - insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY
        } else {
            return outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minX - insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minX
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [CGFloat]

    static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = [0]

    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
````

Comment: I think you should make it much clearer that this is NOT your code, but copied from a GitHub repo - I know you've put "by @maxnatchanon" at the top but it's not clear at all. I was under the impression that you had written it, and was about to credit you with it in a project.

Comment: Also, be careful with this implementation. The offset changes are returned with a @binding property, which cause the reloading of the view each time the value changes. I had 95% of CPU load while scrolling it. The Majid's method, with a simple completion bloc, is way faster (https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/09/24/mastering-scrollview-in-swiftui/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find any option. You can still use the standard `UIScrollView` with their `delegates` with `UIViewRepresentable` by making a separate struct an conforming to it.

**More Detail on that you can find on the SwiftUI Tutorials:**
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why i can't use this example with struct where i can't use "extension". Could you please write me an example code for my case? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I created SwiftPackage for this purpose(Pure SwiftUI )

With this lib, you can get position of ScrollView.

https://github.com/kazuooooo/PositionScrollView

[Medium post](https://medium.com/@matsumotokazuya/how-to-get-set-scroll-position-with-pure-swiftui-4c07d1eace0d)

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

/// Extended ScrollView which can controll position
public struct MinimalHorizontalExample: View, PositionScrollViewDelegate {
    /// Page size of Scroll
    var pageSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
    
    // Create PositionScrollViewModel
    // (Need to create in parent view to bind the state between this view and PositionScrollView)
    @ObservedObject var psViewModel = PositionScrollViewModel(
        pageSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 300),
        horizontalScroll: Scroll(
            scrollSetting: ScrollSetting(pageCount: 5, afterMoveType: .stickNearestUnitEdge),
            pageLength: 200 // Page length of direction
        )
    )
   
    public var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            PositionScrollView(
                viewModel: self.psViewModel,
                delegate: self
            ) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0...4, id: \.self){ i in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(BLUES[i])
                                .border(Color.black)
                                .frame(
                                    width: self.pageSize.width, height: self.pageSize.height
                            )
                            Text("Page\(i)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
              // Get page via scroll object
            Text("page: \(self.psViewModel.horizontalScroll?.page ?? 0)")
              // Get position via scroll object
            Text("position: \(self.psViewModel.horizontalScroll?.position ?? 0)")
        }
    }
    
    struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            return MinimalHorizontalExample()
        }
    }
    
    // Delegate methods of PositionScrollView
      // You can monitor changes of position
    public func onScrollStart() {
        print("onScrollStart")
    }
    public func onChangePage(page: Int) {
        print("onChangePage to page: \(page)")
    }
    
    public func onChangePosition(position: CGFloat) {
        print("position: \(position)")
    }
    
    public func onScrollEnd() {
        print("onScrollEnd")
    }
}
```