# Make scrollbar in ScrollView always visible in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm developing an application in SwiftUI.
I have a horizontal scroll view which shows the scroll bar when the user taps on it. As this app is targeted more towards older users, I want to continually display the scrollbar. I couldn't find anything in the Apple documentation on how to enable this. There's an attribute called *showIndicators* which is true by default and enables the scrollbar by tapping but doesn't continually display the scrollbar. This is a simple code snippet of my ScrollView:

```
 var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
        // other stuff in the scroll view
    }   
 }
```

Comment: You need to build a  custom indicator that moves up/down as you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

After an hour of research, I found this post: [Get the current position of ScrollView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503243/get-the-current-position-of-scrollview-in-swiftui)

It let's me get the current position of a scroll view and I can then move a drawn rectangle (which looks like a scroll bar) according to the tracked position of the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make the scroll bar permanently visible. One thing that might solve your problem is to flash the scroll bar once when the user is first introduced to the collection view to notify them that this view can be scrolled. In UIKit we have this UIScrollView method:

```
scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
```

I don't know if SwiftUI already has something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you must make slider and rotate as vertically ,then you can use with variable at on change slider change value , like this:

```
 ScrollViewReader { reader in
                        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){

                             withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 
                                           4).delay(3)) {
                                                    
                              reader.scrollTo(selectedIndex, anchor: 
                                              UnitPoint.center)
  }
}
```